# Wordpress - Custom Post Type permalinks for post with same title

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I create a custom post type on wordpress. When I publish a new post with the same title of another, wordpress add an auto increment at slug, but doesn't work.

Example:

www.example.com/custom_post_type/test for a post named "Test"
www.example.com/custom_post_type/test-1 for another post named "Test", but the link points to www.example.com/custom_post_type/test

And if I go manually on www.example.com/custom_post_type/test-1 it give me 404 error.

I tried to set:

- has_archive to false
- has_archive to true
- hierarchical to false
- hierarchical to true
- rewrite with 'with_front' to true
- rewrite with 'with_front' to false

and I have always updated permalinks, but nothing, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I tried to remove all plugins installed, but nothing.
I also noticed this problem for the pages and default post types.

Is it a wordpress bug?

Comment: Any interfering plugins or custom code, maybe?

Comment: I don't think: I removed all plugins, and the only custom codes are for create some custom post type and for remove the wordpress logo from the admin login page